# AWS lambda binary data support in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm following [an example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler-using-predefined-interfaces.html)(second example in the page) in AWS official document but got stuck in test. When I sent a plain text request (such as `test`), an exception was thrown.

> com.amazonaws.services.lambda.model.InvalidRequestContentException: Could not parse request body into json: Unrecognized token 'test': was expecting 'null', 'true', 'false' or NaN
>    at [Source: [B@236b619f; line: 1, column: 9]

but when I used a json request (for instance: `{"name": "Tom"}`), everything went well without any error. It seems that lambda tried to parse the request which I don't need it to do. How could I make the example work even the request isn't in json format?

Here's my code which is really almost as same as the code shown in the tutorial.

Example 2: Creating Handler with Stream Input/Output (Leverage the RequestStreamHandler Interface)

```
public class HelloWorldStreamHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {

  @Override
  public void handleRequest(InputStream input, OutputStream output, Context context)
      throws IOException {
    int letter;
    while ((letter = input.read()) != -1) {
      output.write(Character.toUpperCase(letter));
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you've uploaded the latest code to the lambda function and are running test on the latest version?

Comment: @YeshodhanKulkarni Yes. For the code, I downloaded the zip file from S3 and then checked the update time. For the test, I used the latest version of AWS toolkit to do the test.

Comment: I doubt that, cause it is expecting the code in the example, http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/java-handler-using-predefined-interfaces.html -> RequestHandler<Request, Response> where it will ask for the input to be json, as Request has 2 properties firstName and lastName.

Comment: @YeshodhanKulkarni Sorry I didn't mention it but I'm following this one: Example 2: Creating Handler with Stream Input/Output (Leverage the RequestStreamHandler Interface). I will update it in the question.